# CSS/JS Card expanding effect?

Tags: css, material-design

I need to achieve transition effect similar to the card expanding seen on https://pokedex.org

I have checked some of the popular CSS and JS frameworks, but couldn't find this functionality.

Can you please advise on how can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I tried to add animation may be this will work for you

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.mainDiv{
height:300px;
width:300px;
margin:0 auto;
background:rgba(33,150,243,1);
-webkit-animation-name: zoomIn; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    -webkit-animation-duration: .2s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation-name: zoomIn;
    animation-duration: .2s;
}
.secDiv{
height:100px;
width:100px;
top:50px;
position:relative;
margin:0 auto;
background:rgba(133,50,24,1);
-webkit-animation-name: slideUp; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    -webkit-animation-duration: .6s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation-name: slideUp;
    animation-duration: .6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideUp {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    visibility: visible;
  }

  to {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes slideUp {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    visibility: visible;
  }

  to {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoomIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
    transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes zoomIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
    transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


</style>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="mainDiv">
     <div class="secDiv">
     </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```